# Each item of scrapy output is being placed in a separate row in csv

Tags: python, scrapy, export-to-csv

I've scraped more than 5,000 links from a csv file.

The program is putting each element into a separate row in the output csv.

How can I get one row per website with all the information for a website in the same row?

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_tags
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from bkstr.items import BkstrItem
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.loader.processors import Join
import csv
import sys


class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "book"
    my_file = open("callnumberedited3.csv", "rb")
    reader = csv.reader(my_file)
    start_urls = my_file
    custom_settings = {'REDIRECT_ENABLED': False}
    handle_httpstatus_list = [301]
    download_delay = 0.25
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(), follow=True, callback='parse_item')]

    def parse_item (self, response):
        items = []
        varx = response.xpath('//*[@id="fldset-course_1_1"]/div[2]/h2/text()')

        for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="fldset-course_1_1"]/div[2]/h2/text()'):
            item = BkstrItem()
            item["course"] = varx.extract()[0]
            yield item

        var1 = response.xpath('//*[@id="fldset-crsmaterialgrp_1"]/div[1]/h3/text()') 
        for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="fldset-crsmaterialgrp_1"]/div[1]/h3/text()'):
            item = BkstrItem()
            item["title1"] = var1.extract()[0]
            yield item

        var11 = response.xpath('//*[@id="materialAuthor"]/text()')
        for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="materialAuthor"]/text()'):
            item = BkstrItem()
            item["author1"] = var11.extract() 
            yield item

        var12 = response.xpath('//*[@id="materialISBN"]/text()')
        for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="materialISBN"]/text()'):
            item = BkstrItem()
            item["isbn1"] = var12.extract() 
            yield item

        var15 = response.xpath('//*[@id="materialCopyrightYear"]/text()')
        for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="materialCopyrightYear"]/text()'):
            item = BkstrItem()
            item["year1"] = var15.extract() 
            yield item

        var16 = response.xpath('//*[@id="materialPublisher"]/text()')
        for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="materialPublisher"]/text()'):
            item = BkstrItem()
            item["publisher1"] = var16.extract()                        
            yield item  

        var2 = response.xpath('//*[@id="fldset-crsmaterialgrp_2"]/div[1]/h3/text()')
        for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="fldset-crsmaterialgrp_2"]/div[1]/h3/text()'):
            item = BkstrItem()
            item["title2"] = var2.extract()[0]
            yield item

        var3 = response.xpath('//*[@id="fldset-crsmaterialgrp_3"]/div[1]/h3/text()')
        for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="fldset-crsmaterialgrp_3"]/div[1]/h3/text()'):
            item = BkstrItem()
            item["title3"] = var3.extract()[0]
            yield item
        print items
```

Comment: What is the desired outcome?

Comment: Your indentation looks wrong. Can you fix it in your question?

Comment: @JeroenHeier The desired outcome is that it outputs the course name and all other data next to it. Now it just starts a new row with each new element. I'd like it so that it each time it runs through these items it stays in the same row. Only moving to next row once it starts scraping the next website

Comment: @paultrmbrth Fixed. Sorry about that.